# Redirect from a php page to a html page

Tags: php, html

How do i redirect from a php page to html page ,header isnt working in the following code

```
<?php include "submit.html";
define('DB_NAME','form');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','toor');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link)
{
    die('could not connect : ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$link);
if(!$db_selected)
{
    die('Can\'t use ' .DB_NAME . ': ' .mysql_error());
}
$value1 = $_POST['fname'];
$value2 = $_POST['Place'];
$value3 = $_POST['Country'];
$value4 = $_POST['rname'];
$value5 = $_POST['food'];
$value6 = $_POST['ambience'];
$value7 = $_POST['service'];
$value8 = $_POST['clean'];
$value9 = $_POST['pfacility'];
$value10 = $_POST['Entertainment'];
$value11 = $_POST['suggestions'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO demo1 (fname,Place,Country,rname,food,ambience,service,clean,Parking_facilities,Entertainment,suggestions) VALUES ('$value1','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7','$value8','$value9','$value10','$value11')";
if(!mysql_query($sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close();
header('Location: localhost/submit.html',true);
?>
```

How do i redirect from here and why is the above code not working?

Comment: Missing semicolon after the `include` statement?

Comment: Define "not working"? What error do you get? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: 'not working' - in what way is it 'not working'? Is there an error message? Does anything happen at all?

Comment: Unless you have a `localhost` directory in your site's document root, which contains that html file, you're redirecting to a page that doesn't exist. It should probably be just `Location: submit.html`, or better yet, `Location: http://localhost/submit.html`.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: It doesnt redirect to any page

Comment: I wanted to redirect this to the submit.html page but it doesnt redirect even after using header. --john conde

Comment: what's it showing? a blank page? can you try adding `error_reporting(-1);` at the beginning to force error show?

Comment: It shows a blank page and in the url i still have my php page and it doesnt redirect to submit.html

Comment: you should try ob_start() on the top of the page, and then give header('Location:submit.html')  OR use JS redirection echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location.href = "submit.html"; </script>';

Answer (score 0):

I think MarkB has your answer. That is, the correct syntax would be:

```
header('Location: http://localhost/submit.html',true);
```

However, if that doesn't solve the problem you can try this:

```
echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=submit.html">';
```

`header()` will fail if any other output was sent to the browser previously, and the above will succeed in those cases.

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* his `header()` call isn't working.

Comment: Note that the command I suggested is a PHP command. Try putting just the HTML part in the body of the page and see if that command will redirect to a different page (if it works, you will go straight to the second page). To recap: just put in this part: `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=anotherpage.html">` -- but first make sure that there is a page called `anotherpage.html` in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `header()` after you already sent text to the browser, in this case from `include "submit.html";`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: i deleted the include and it still doesnt forward the page.